# Twitter BootStrap Scrollspy Bug still persistant...?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

Read the github documentation, bug is well know and it was suppose to have been fixed in 2.1..
but it hasn't?

Essentially... you can offset the data the scrollspy uses HOWEVER that offset does NOT affect the actual clicking of the tab.

Any help on finding a solution?

This is the site I am trying to fix: www.powerliftingbasics.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @fat's comment on [Issue #3316: Scrollspy Bugs](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3316#issuecomment-6082310):

> `$('.navbar').scrollspy({offest: 70});` is only intended to modify
>   scrolling calculations - we don't shift the actual anchor click stuff,
>   that's on you. The plugin is only for spying on scrolls.

That is, ScrollSpy just observes, it doesn't control browser scroll.

The Twitter Bootstrap page solves it by using a `padding-top: 30px` on the sections that are linked to.  Otherwise you could deal with it with JS:

```
function adjustScrollForNavbar() {
  var $nav = $('div.navbar')
  if ( $nav.css('position') !== "fixed" ) return
  window.scrollBy(0, -$nav.height())
}

// Adjust for fixed navbar
$('body').on('click.scroll-adjust', '[href^="#"]', function (e) {
  if ( e && e.isDefaultPrevented() ) return
  $(window).one('scroll', adjustScrollForNavbar )
});
```

Obviously the CSS fix would be preferable.

Comment: The CSS fix is horrible. The padding makes the site look so bad... bc its empty content and then the title if you just want to scroll.

Comment: Understood. The reason it works on the Bootstrap site is that the background of the padded section corresponds with the page background overall. So, everything just comes out as whitespace and it just looks like well spaced typography. The CSS padding is not a patch-like fix, it's something you would need to plan into your layout.  You might consider having the in-page navigation anchored to an element which doesn't have a different background color.